# How to add custom fields and business logics in firebase auth UI Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using firebase's [pre-build auth UI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) and which seems very helpful to me reducing a lot of boilerplate code. But I'm facing some limitations. For email registration using prebuild auth UI, there are only the three fields I'm getting (*Email, First and last name, password*) showing the attached image below.

But I need to add some extra fields (*Address, Postal code, etc*) and apply some business logic like **confirm password**, **password strength check**, etc.

I got a solution from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45246653/trying-to-set-confirm-password-with-firebase-auth) but it is not applicable for **pre-build auth UI**.

[image]

Comment: Firebase UI is open source.  You can modify it to do anything you want.  https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: Can you please kindly share with me any materials that show how to make it locally  @DougStevenson